# True or false statements regarding binomial distribution (variance, poission-distribution etc.)

Tags: approximation, variance, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ be binomially distributed with parameters $n$ and $p$, i.e. $X \sim Bin(n,p), q := 1- p \in (0,1)$

$a)$ $X$ represents the number of white balls when taking $n $ balls out of an urn without putting them back with $w$ balls being white and $p = w/n$.

$b)$ $X$ is approximately normally distributed when $p$ is small.

$c)$ $E(X) = np$

$d)$ $X$ does not have a variance

$e)$ $X$ is approximately Poisson-distributed, when $n$ and $q$ are big

We have the following answers, but we are unsure, if these are correct:

$a)$ False because we can't put the balls back into the urn

$b)$ False. It's only true when $p$ is big

$c)$ True

$d)$ False (because every distribution has variance)

$e)$ True (because poission is strictly positive)

Any correction or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(e) is true because Poisson is a good approximation to Binomial when $n$ is large and $p$ is small. The question says $q$ is large, ie. $p=1-q$ is small. So that's why (e) is true. http://bestmaths.net/online/index.php/year-levels/year-12/year-12-topic-list/poisson-approximation-binomial/

Other than that, your answers seem correct to me.

Comment: Your reason in your answer to part b) is not quite correct in my opinion. I agree it is false, but it's not "only true when $p$ is big."  For $X$ to be approximately normally distributed, $p$ should be near to 0.5 (i.e. not too big or small.) However if $n$ is really large, $X$ can be approximately normal even if $p$ is big or small.